# Using findOne with Arrays in Mongoose with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, mongoose

in NodeJS with Mongoose, how do i search something **in** an array using `findOne()`? I want to search stuff like `626ead978edc5f2a3f7ca924` in the `users` array in my `sessionCollection`-Model.
My DB looks like this: [Database Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfWcu.png)

Comment: Did you check this? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll work normally as it does for non array key:

```
SessionCollection.findOne({users: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("626ead978edc5f2a3f7ca924")})
```

You might need to cast to objectId to get the desired result.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451358/mongoose-mongo-find-in-array-of-objectids)

Comment: I tried it but it didnt return me anything, neither after the curl or in the node-console, tried [this](https://pastebin.com/rpKSX188). Console logging the `inSession` directly, outputs `"null"`

Comment: Sorry, didnt look in here for a few days, thank you, that works actually